# how to define an array of IPs in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 5.3. In an index, I want to define a field as an array of `ip` fields. How do I define this in a mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mapping for IPs can also be used for arrays of IPs.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "ip_addr": {
          "type": "ip"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here you just index the IPs as an array.

```
PUT my_index/my_type/1
{
  "ip_addr": ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2"]
}
```

And then you can search them as usual.

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "ip_addr": "192.168.0.0/16"
    }
  }
}
```

The mapping for single entries and arrays is actually always the same in Elasticsearch (for primitive datatypes).

Answer (score 2):

You should use ip data type:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "ip_addr": {
          "type": "ip"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Official docs for ip data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ip.html)

Comment: That is only for a single IP. I need for an array of IPs.

Comment: you can also use for arrays